# How can I validate with a test a json with all the parameters? Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, validation, testautomationfx

Example:
{ "name": "Jocelyne",
"age": 30
}
and it returns the same. In case someone adds more parameters it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you correctly, you can write a function like this (to check the keywords)

```
import json

def check_json_data(json_str):
    # base key list
    base_keys = json.loads('{ "name": "Jocelyne", "age": 30 }').keys()
    # convert json string to dict
    input_json_data = json.loads(json_str)
    # extract keys
    input_keys = input_json_data.keys()
    # check if there are additional keys in incoming keys
    if set(input_keys) - set(base_keys): # for exact check of key list: set(input_keys) != set(base_keys)
        return None
    else:
        return json_str
```

Test

```
print(check_json_data('{ "name": "Jocelyne", "age": 30, "age2": 30 }'))

print(check_json_data('{ "name": "Jocelyne", "age2": 30 }'))

print(check_json_data('{ "name": "Jose", "age": 33 }'))
```

> None

> None

> { "name": "Joce", "age": "33" }